# Errors when linking against clang

Tags: c, linker, clang, linker-errors

I feel like I'm missing something very simple here. I want to play around with clang, so as a starting point I followed the code example in [this video, around 3:40](http://devimages.apple.com/llvm/videos/Libclang.mov). The code is as follows:

```
#include "clang-c/Index.h" // Note: These two lines were 
#include <stdio.h>         // omitted from the video slides
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CXIndex Index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
    CXTranslationUnit TU = clang_parseTranslationUnit(Index, 0, argv, argc, 0, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None);
    for (unsigned I = 0, N = clang_getNumDiagnostics(TU); I != N; ++I)
    {
        CXDiagnostic Diag = clang_getDiagnostic(TU, I);
        CXString String = clang_formatDiagnostic(Diag, clang_defaultDiagnosticDisplayOptions());
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", clang_getCString(String));
        clang_disposeString(String);
    }
    clang_disposeTranslationUnit(TU);
    clang_disposeIndex(Index);
    return 0;
}
```

In the video, he does not states that he's omitted the two `#include` directives. I think I correctly filled those in in my example above. He also omits how the file was compiled and linked, which is the part I'm having trouble with. Following the instructions [here](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) I checked out and compiled clang and llvm. The files were checked out to `~/src/llvm` then compiled from `~/src/build` (just as the instructions say), and now I'm trying to make the simple test project above in `~/src/test`. Below is how I'm calling gcc, and the output.

```
gcc -I../llvm/tools/clang/include/ -L../build/Debug+Asserts/lib/ -lclang main.cpp -o test
/tmp/ccrpABsq.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `clang_createIndex'
main.cpp:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `clang_parseTranslationUnit'
main.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `clang_getNumDiagnostics'
main.cpp:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `clang_getDiagnostic'
main.cpp:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `clang_defaultDiagnosticDisplayOptions'
main.cpp:(.text+0xab): undefined reference to `clang_formatDiagnostic'
main.cpp:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `clang_getCString'
main.cpp:(.text+0xed): undefined reference to `clang_disposeString'
main.cpp:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to `clang_disposeTranslationUnit'
main.cpp:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `clang_disposeIndex'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I checked `~/build/Debut+Asserts/lib` and there is both `libclang.a` and `libclang.so` in that directory. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried googling around and haven't found any tips, or instructions on what I should be linking against. Regardless, I've tried a few different things and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `-lclang` after `main.cpp`. The order of arguments matters to `gcc`, as it resolves symbols from static libraries in order. See also [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc).

Comment: Oh god I'm an idiot. I realized this right as your answer showed up. Thanks.